# Can't save photos from email

Tags: pantheon-mail

Im not able save photos emailed to me. If I right click the photo the only option is to "select all". If I select all and right click to try to paste into the Pictures file there is no option to paste.

If I try to drag and drop to the Pictures folder I get "Error while copying" and "The specified location is not supported".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have this problem too. I hope someone answers soon.

Comment: Do you mean the photos are embedded in the body of the email instead of attached?

Answer (score 1):

This feature seems to be not supported in current version of Pantheon Mail. I tested with embedded image and I can reproduce your problem.

However the current version of Geary 3.32 supports this (via right-click). Pantheon Mail was forked from Geary, if I'm not misteaken.

I would consider [reporting](https://github.com/elementary/mail/issues) this to elementary OS developers as a bug/feature request. They could either backport it from Geary or include it in future release.

In the meantime you can use Geary from e.g. Flathub.org to achieve this or access the mail via web interface.

Comment: I only found one partially solved [bug report](https://github.com/elementary/mail/issues/20) concerning this, so I raised a question if the second part can be resolved too.