# Saving photos from the Mail app

Tags: pantheon

How can I save photos from Mail? All I seem to be able to do is Select All. These do not show as attachments.

Comment: Do you mean the photos are embedded in the body of the email instead of attached?

Comment: possible duplicate (needs clarification): https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/19203/cant-save-photos-from-email

Comment: Also please don't open identical questions to the ones you already found. Instead upvote the question that fits your problem.

Comment: I believe they are embedded. Sorry for the bad etiquette. I’m a newbie.

Comment: No worries :) check out the answer I gave in the other older post (it's linked above as possible duplicate)